# Choosing between two types of Meta Tags

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, metatag

I am trying to get the meta tags from websites and echo the result, it is working well so far, but I found an external problem...

I am using this code:

```
static private function _parse($HTML) {
    $old_libxml_error = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($HTML);

    libxml_use_internal_errors($old_libxml_error);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('meta');
    if (!$tags || $tags->length === 0) {
        return false;
    }

    $page = new self();

    foreach ($tags AS $tag) {
        if ($tag->hasAttribute('property') &&
            strpos($tag->getAttribute('property'), 'og:') === 0) {
            $key = strtr(substr($tag->getAttribute('property'), 3), '-', '_');
            $page->_values[$key] = $tag->getAttribute('content');
        }
    }


    if (empty($page->_values)) { return false; }

    return $page;
}
```

When the URL that I'm trying to fetch has the meta tags using the attibute 'property' (Ex: `<meta property="title">`) everything goes fine, as the code is suppose to do... but some URLs uses the attribute 'name' (Ex: `<meta name="title">`) instead 'property'...

So, I need to find a solution to extract the values from 'property' and if it's empty, return the values from 'name'...

I tried some things, but do not succed so far.. Anyone have ideas?

Comment: `str_ireplace('<meta property','<meta name',$HTML);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this

```
foreach ($tags AS $tag) {
    if ($tag->hasAttribute('property') &&
        strpos($tag->getAttribute('property'), 'og:') === 0) {
        $key = strtr(substr($tag->getAttribute('property'), 3), '-', '_');
        $page->_values[$key] = $tag->getAttribute('content');
    } else if ($tag->hasAttribute('name') &&
        strpos($tag->getAttribute('name'), 'og:') === 0) {
        $key = strtr(substr($tag->getAttribute('name'), 3), '-', '_');
        $page->_values[$key] = $tag->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
```

As OZ_ noticed, you could use str_ireplace to rename all meta name to meta property.

Comment: Thanks! This solve the problem! :)

Well, I have another one to solve now... I'm using 'curl' to fetch the Url and there some sites that I just can't extract the meta datas at all, even if it's well formed (I know that by checking the source code)... So, I think that the problem could be that the UrL that I'm trying to fetch are blocking me from extract the content, is that possible?

This is happening with the New York Times web site http://www.nytimes.com/

Comment: That is possible, they could use several filter to screen all webrequests to their website. I don't know why they would to that though, unless you we're using lots of resources. You could alter some curl settings; or echo the 'raw' output of curl to check if is matches the source code that you have seen. I never used curl before, so cant help you with that. There are many curl options though, look them up here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php